# how to remove hibernation error in android application?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

hey guys i upload my application on amazon market place m getting the error

Bug Description:"App name" was found to be incompatible because of issues with the app’s interaction with Kindle Fire's hibernation feature."App Name (Kindle Tablet Edition)" force closes, crashes, or loses user state after the device hibernates and then resumes.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Install and launch the app.
2. Hibernate the device.
3. Unlock the device.
4. The app exits to the device home screen.

Please correct the issue(s) we found with your app submission.

plz help me m stuck in this what is hibernation m didnt  get it

Comment: Hibernation in the Android context is when the device returns to standby state. In this instance it appears that when the user lets their device sleep your application isn't handling it correctly but without more detail on what your app is doing on the exact issue there's not much help we can give here. Do you have a logcat for instance?

Answer (score 0):

When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.

android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Please ensure to include the above attribute in your manifest file.

Hope this info resolve your issue.